# How to draw lines and put text above figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth,trim={0 50 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a};
    \includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a};
    \includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a};
    \includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a};
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Given the historical human and object motion}
    \label{fig:intro}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But this is what I get

[image]

Where did the other figure go? How do I draw the line with reference to the left figure? e.g.

```
\node[] (image) at (a=0,b=0) {\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\draw (a,b) -- (a+10,b);
```

Also, why is the first image not being cropped?

Comment: You put the first graphics in a node but the others are not in nodes, hence your problems. You want to put all graphics in nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you put the graphics in the tikz picture but you really want to wrap them in nodes. You can put them next to each other automatically using a `chain`. And you can draw the lines by using anchors of these nodes. Conveniently chains have predefined nodes `-begin` and `-end`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=g going right,node distance=1mm, 
        nodes={inner sep=0,on chain}]
    \node[anchor=south west] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth,trim={0 50 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \draw (g-begin.south west|-g-end.south)+(-1mm,-1mm) -- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]g-end.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Given the historical human and object motion}
    \label{fig:intro}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what does ([xshift=0,yshift=0]g-end.south east) mean ?

Comment: thank you, i played around with the values and got an idea of what they represent